# How to properly handle comma inside a quoted string using opencsv?

Tags: java, parsing, javabeans, opencsv

I'm trying to read csv file that contains strings both quoted and not.

- If string is quoted, it should save it's quote chars.
- Beside that, if string contains comma, it should not be split.

I've tried multiple ways but nothing works as of now.

Current test data:

```
"field1 (with use of , we lose the other part)",some description
field2,"Dear %s, some text"
```

**Getting 1st field of mapped bean**

Expected result:

```
"field1 (with use of , we lose the other part)"
field2
```

Current result:

```
"field1 (with use of 
field2
```

Here is the code:

```
public class CsvToBeanReaderTest {

    @Test
    void shouldIncludeDoubleQuotes() {
        String testData =
                "\"field1 (with use of , we lose the other part)\",some description\n"
                        +
                        "field2,\"Dear %s, some text\"";

        RFC4180ParserBuilder rfc4180ParserBuilder = new RFC4180ParserBuilder();
        rfc4180ParserBuilder.withQuoteChar(ICSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
        ICSVParser rfc4180Parser = rfc4180ParserBuilder.build();
        CSVReaderBuilder builder = new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(testData));

        CSVReader reader = builder
                .withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser)
                .build();

        List<TestClass> result = new CsvToBeanBuilder<TestClass>(reader)
                .withType(TestClass.class)
                .withEscapeChar('\"')
                .build()
                .parse();

        result.forEach(testClass -> System.out.println(testClass.getField1()));
    }

    private List<TestClass> readTestData(String testData) {
        return new CsvToBeanBuilder<TestClass>(new StringReader(testData))
                .withType(TestClass.class)
                .withSeparator(',')
                .withSkipLines(0)
                .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
                .build()
                .parse();
    }

    public static final class TestClass {
        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 0)
        private String field1;

        @CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
        private String description;

        public String toCsvFormat() {
            return String.join(",",
                    field1,
                    description);
        }

        public String getField1() {
            return field1;
        }
    }
}
```

I've found out that if I comment or remove `rfc4180ParserBuilder.withQuoteChar(ICSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);` the string will be parsed correctly, but I will lose the quote char which should not be lost. Is there any suggestions what can be done? **(I would prefer not to switch on other csv libraries)**

Comment: If a string is quoted, whatever it contains is irrelevant: the cell content continues until the closing quote. *Ergo* no special treatment of the comma is required. You are correct in asserting that the quotes should be retained. Your code is an unholy mess frankly. It would be simpler to write it yourself than try to unite all these disparate methods and functions.

Comment: @user207421 I do agree that this code is a mess right now, sorry for that. Regarding problem with csv data - the file is not formatted according to RFC 4180 and it can't be changed. That's the only reason this post was even made. I will try to find another solution, thank you for your reply!